# Four textareas with each two arrows

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, arrows

I took a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mgfv8nk8/9/

`$("#btnLeft").click(function () {`

there's two text area, one on each sides. What I would simply like to do is to add two more text areas but another two sets of left and right arrows along with.

Text area 1 (primary table that shows the list) works with text area 2
put on left and right arrow

Text area 4 (secondary table that shows the list) works with text area 3
put on left and right arrow

*Note:* Text area 2 must be only with Text area 1 by using the arrows
Text area 4 must only work with text area 3

Is there a way to expand this code?

Comment: Do you also want left right between 2nd & 3rd Text-area?